# Is there available a complete set of JavaScript (ECMAScript) parser test cases?

Tags: javascript, parsing

I am going to write a JavaScript parser, I would like a set of test cases, i.e., things that *should* parse into *what* (and possibly things that *should not* parse) that I can throw at my parser to test its correctness. I don't want to test running of JavaScript, *just* parsing.

I am reading through the ECMAScript spec and creating a set of test-cases from that, but if someone's already done it, that's great.

I also had a look at the V8 and SpiderMonkey sources for test cases but, apart from being baffled by the hand-coded parsers, the parse tests seem to be combined with evaluation tests.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how would you expect a parser tester to work if it's not testing actual interpretation?  In other words, what sort of output would be sufficiently generic among parsers that standardized, packaged tests could actually be useful?

Comment: A test that looks for (1) things that *should* parse, and (2) things that *should not* parse would be general enough, because it's just a boolean. The more interesting tests would have to have a portable AST representation format, e.g. XML, SExprs or JSON. I'm quite happy with the ones CMS posted that are implementation-specific, because I can easily translate them into my testing format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can give you two starting points, from two recent projects:

A couple of months ago, Peter van der Zee (aka [@kuvos](http://twitter.com/kuvos)) made an [ECMAScript 5 parser](http://esparser.qfox.nl), his parser includes some syntax-dedicated tests and a fuzzer, [jsfunfuz](http://www.squarefree.com/2007/08/02/introducing-jsfunfuzz/) by Jesse Ruderman.

Check [EsParser.js](http://esparser.qfox.nl/EsParser.js) (look for the `EsParser.testSuite` function) to find some of those tests.

There's other ECMAScript 5 parser written in ECMAScript, this one if from the Google's [ES-Lab](http://es-lab.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/site/esparser/index.html) project, they have also a good set of syntax-oriented unit tests that you can find [here](http://code.google.com/p/es-lab/source/browse/trunk/tests/parser/).

Comment: @Christopher, you're welcome!. If you want, whenever you finish your parser I would be happy to give it a look (I'm good finding parsing bugs :P). One of the most complex task you will find while implementing your parser will be IMO, the Automatic Semicolon Insertion process, there are a lot of lexical conventions that one can miss... Good luck :) P.S. By the way, in which language will you implement it?

Comment: Indeed, the automatic semicolon insertion is given a lot of time in the ECMAScript. That'll be fun to get right. Thanks for offering, I'll drop you a message when I'm done. ;-) It'll be in Haskell using Parsec. I made a brief start last night, I am almost done parsing identifier names (kind of weird that var \uC0 = 1; is valid JavaScript, haven't read the motivations behind it but it is odd). Here's a gist so far: https://gist.github.com/def7743db5a74da6329b I might update this until I have a complete parser at which point I'll put it on Github.